(Infinite) sum of products of 'offset' Bessel functions (an application to calculating the RMS power of a harmonic "FM" oscillator)
TLDR version: I'm trying to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a)$ but can't seem to get it right. For motivation & attempt, read the rest.
Consider the harmonic "FM" oscillator where the period of modulator matches that of the carrier.
$$ s(t) = \sin(\omega x + a \sin(\omega x)) $$
By the "Bessel expansion", in this particular case we get
$$s(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(a)\sin ((n+1)\omega x)$$
I want to calculate the (RMS) power of this signal. To actually make this a Fourier series in order to apply Parseval's identity, we need to group the coefficients of the same frequencies, which in this (1:1 carrier modulator case) match up as 0:-2, 1:-3 etc. with the "reflected" frequencies in engineering speak. (The -1 index term would be the 0-frequency DC, but that can be ignored here due the 'sin' form we've chosen with zero phase.) So, that gives the Fourier series:
$$s(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (J_{n-1}(a) - J_{-n-1}(a))\sin (n\omega x) $$
So, now the problem statement is to calculate (the square of the RMS power) as a function of the 'modulation index' $a$:
$$ P(a)^2= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (J_{n-1}(a) - J_{-n-1}(a))^2 $$
(If you're curious if the above is correctly calculating the power here, I did check it out numerically on desmos--notation I used there differs slightly.)
Does this sum admit a 'closed form', i.e. can the right hand side be calculated in any simpler fashion?
I did look through the DMLF page on Bessel function properties, but I'm not seeing how to tackle that sum after a certain point. Expanding the expression under the sum gives:
$$ P(a)^2= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [J_{n-1}(a)^2 + J_{-n-1}(a)^2 - 2J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a)] $$
Applying  "10.23.3" [Neuman's addition theorem] in a suitably modified form, i.e that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1+J_0(a)^2)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{-n-1}(a)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n+1} (a)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1-J_0(a)^2)-J_1(a)^2$ reduces the first two terms under the expression for $P^(a)$ to just $-\frac{1}{2}J_1(a)^2$, i.e.
$$ P(a)^2= \frac{1-J_1(a)^2}{2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a) $$
(I checked numerically on desmos that the latter expression is correct as well.) But I'm not sure how to calculate the remaining infinite sum, even though its value is relatively small for the values of $a$ I tried (to about 5 or so), i.e. first part of the expression is a reasonable approximation for small $a$. To proceed from here to calculate the rest, it looks like I can apply (the more general) 10.23.2 Neuman addition formula to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a)$. But I'm struggling to figure out how to cast that as a sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to apply 10.23.2. First step would be rewrite it so one of the factors is $J_{n}(a)$ and the offset appears only in the other, so $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} J_{n}(a) J_{-2-n}(a)$. Now it looks like how we should apply 10.23.2 is for $y = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n}(a) J_{-2-n}(a) = J_{-2}(2a) = J_2(2a) $. By a "symmetry argument" $x=\frac{y}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(J_0(a)J_{-2}(a)) = \frac{1}{2} (J_2(2a) + J_0(a)J_{2}(a))$ . However, this is quite wrong numerically. So what's my mistake here, or what should $x$ (the remaining sum) really be?

N.B. After inserting the right formula for the remaining sum, there's another cancellation, and the result for $P(a)^2$ is just $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} J_2(2a)$.

In case somebody cares about a more general result: if the carrier to modulator frequency ratio is $nf : 2f$,  with $n$ integer. then the square of the power of the modulated signal is  $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}J_{-n}(2a)$. Yeah, it also is the case that for modulators more than twice the carrier frequency (e.g. 1:3, 1:4 etc.) the power of the modulated signal stays constant regardless of the modulation index. The highest power variation attainable via FM is in the 1:2 case because $J_{-1}$ has the highest amplitude variation among these.

Actually, the last sentence in the previous cmt was wrong. The $n=0$ case makes sense too (i.e. carrier being DC), and it turns out the square of the power is then driven by $J_0(2a)$, which has the highest variation. But this case is not so common because the peak amplitude also varies with the modulation index $a$ in this case, unlike for non-DC carriers.

Consider:
$$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a)$$
If we make the change of variable $j= -n$:
$$S= \sum_{j=-1}^{-\infty} J_{-j-1}(a) J_{j-1}(a)$$
Therefore
$$2S = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=-1} J_{n-1}(a)J_{-n-1}(a) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a)J_{-n-1}(a)$$
Now adding and substracting $J^2_{-1}(a)$:
$$2S =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a)J_{-n-1}(a) - J_{-1}^2(a)$$
Hence
$$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a) -\frac{1}{2}J^2_{-1}(a)$$
If you make the change of variable $k=n-1$
$$S=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{k}(a) J_{-k-2}(a)-\frac{1}{2}J^2_{-1}(a) $$
and using the Newmann's addition theorem:
$$ J_v(x\pm y) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{v\mp j}(x)J_j(x)$$
$$S=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{k}(a) J_{-k-2}(a) - \frac{1}{2}J^2_{-1} = \frac{1}{2}J_{-2}(2a)-\frac{1}{2}J^2_{-1}(a) $$
Finally, using this property:
$$J_{-n}(x) = (-1)^{n}J_{n}(x)$$
$$S=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{k}(a) J_{-k-2}(a)-J_{-1}(a) =  \frac{1}{2}J_{2}(2a)-\frac{1}{2}J_{1}^2(a) $$
Therefore
$$ \boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(a) J_{-n-1}(a) = \frac{1}{2}J_{2}(2a)-\frac{1}{2}J_{1}^2(a)}$$

Much appreciated. I had the "correction" for the 0 index wrong obviously in my "symmetry argument".
